# Unicode null symbol in text parsed from file leading to failing equality checks

Tags: ruby, file, text, unicode

I'm running ruby 1.9.3 on Cygwin64. I'm downloading a zip-file and parsing the contained file based on the beginning of each line like so:

```
open(fpath, 'wb') do |file|
    file << open(url).read
end
logpath = Pathname.new("./tmp.log")
Zip::File.open(fpath) do |zipfile|
   zipfile.each do |file|
      file.extract(logpath.to_s){true}
   end
end 

logfile = open(logpath, 'r')
logfile.each do |line|
   if line == "SOMETHING"
      #do something
   end
end
```

The code inside the `if` statement never runs. That's because:

```
"SOMETHING".inspect = "SOMETHING"
```

and

```
line.inspect = "\u0000S\u0000O\u0000M\u0000E\u0000T\u0000H\u0000I\u0000N\u0000G
```

I'm stumped as to why the unicode null escape code is present before every character in `line`. The only solutions I've found are:

```
system("dos2unix #{logpath}")
```

and

```
line.encode!("UTF-16le", "UTF-8", :invalid => :replace, :undefined => :replace, replace: "")
line.encode!("UTF-8", "UTF-16le")
line.gsub!("\u0000", "")
```

Is there a better way to handle this? Am I doing something incorrectly extracting the logfile that's causing this problem?

Any and all comments and answers much appreciated!

**Solution**

Open the file for reading as a UTF-16 little endian file:

```
logfile = open(logpath, 'rb:UTF-16le')
```

Then encode each line (or the full body of text if you want)

```
line.encode!("UTF-8", "UTF-16le", :invalid => :replace, :undefined => :replace, replace: "")
```

And voila! Thanks Denis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your code correctly, your log file is encoded in utf16 rather than utf8, so you could open it accordingly and let ruby do the conversion on the fly. Example:

```
>> f = File.open("iso-8859-1.txt", "r:iso-8859-1:utf-8")
=> #<File:iso-8859-1.txt>
>> f.external_encoding.name
=> "ISO-8859-1"
>> content = f.read
=> "This file contains umlauts: äöü"
>> content.encoding.name
=> "UTF-8"
```

http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/ruby-1-9-encodings/

Comment: Yes, I'd tried this but there were still some invalid symbols being included in the file. However, combining this approach with an additional `encode!` step makes it work. I've edited my question to post the solution.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check it might be some issue related to big endian vs little endian. It seems a bit crazy that a log file, of all things, might be storing garbage. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I think it has something to do with the way I'm extracting the file from the zip (or how rubyzip is doing it...). When I run my original code on the logfile directly (without downloading the zip and extracting in my code), none of the unicode null symbols show up.

Comment: Add a magic encoding line to the top of your file (see and be sure to read the lengthy link I posted), if you haven't already; that might help too. Especially if your own computer and interpreter is running in utf-16 (asia?) or something like that.