# convert unicode to text in ruby

Tags: ruby, unicode

I downloaded a tab delimited file, and am trying to create a script to read it, but the lines are coming out like this:

```
"\xFF\xFEu\x00s\x00e\x00r\x00-\x00r\x00e\x00p\x00o\x00r\x00t\x00-\x00s\x00e\x00a
\x00r\x00c\x00h\x00-\x00r\x00e\x00s\x00u\x00l\x00t\x00s\x00-\x002\x000\x001\x004
\x000\x001\x000\x009\x001\x002\x000\x006\x000\x007\x00-\x00G\x00M\x00T\x00.\x00\
t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\
x00\r\x00\n"
```

I believe I need to convert (unicode?) to simple text. Is there a string method that does this? I searched [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html), but couldn't understand which one does the trick. Below (with a series of tabs) is what I see when I open the file in a regular text editor, for the line quoted above:

```
"user-report-search-results-20140109120607-GMT."
```

Comment: Can you provide the script you currently use to read the file and maybe the file itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches and with help from [another forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ruby_ireland/d-Bu6_WmzGo), I managed to use CSV instead. This was the code that worked for me:

```
CSV.foreach(filename, { :row_sep => :auto, :col_sep => "\t", :encoding => 'UTF-16:UTF-8'}) do |row|
```

In the end, CSV suited me better, because this is a tab-delimited file.

Thank you all for your comments anyway !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`String#encode`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-encode):

Aside: seeing all those null chars, I suspect your source encoding is utf16 (not sure if it's little or big endian). You probably want it in utf8.

Also, note that you can convert a file on the fly:

```
>> f = File.open("iso-8859-1.txt", "r:iso-8859-1:utf-8")
=> #<File:iso-8859-1.txt>
>> f.external_encoding.name
=> "ISO-8859-1"
>> content = f.read
=> "This file contains umlauts: äöü"
>> content.encoding.name
=> "UTF-8"
```

http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/ruby-1-9-encodings/

See also this related question:

[Unicode null symbol in text parsed from file leading to failing equality checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20961861/unicode-null-symbol-in-text-parsed-from-file-leading-to-failing-equality-checks/)

Comment: what is the use-case of checking `#external_encoding` ? I didn't ever use it before thus asking..

Comment: Neither have I, tbh. The example is from nuclearsquid.com. As I understand it, though, it hold's the original file's encoding, before ruby converts it (to utf8 in the above). I'm guessing perhaps to conditionally convert files or something to that order.

Comment: f = File.open(filename, "r:utf-16:utf-8") worked, but in the end I was able to use CSV instead, since this was actually a tab-delimited file. Initially I didn't think I could use it because I was having some CSV malformed errors, but I managed to find a solution, which I'll post as the answer. Thank you for your help anyway !